# Handling sharepoint workflow differences between dev, test and production

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

How do you handle having different time delays and sending notifications to different users based on the environment they are running in (dev, test & production)?

We are developing long running workflows that we would like to have delay for minutes in our dev and test environments, but need to delay for days in production.

These same workflows need to send their notifications to us in the dev environment and business users in the test and production environments.

What are the best practices for handling these types of situations?

Comment: Are you creating your workflow in Visual Studio, or SharePoint Designer?

Comment: I take it that you're using designer based on your tags, so I'll answer assuming that.

Comment: Kyle - Yes it is SharePoint Designer. I'm not the one doing the development and right now Visual Studio is off the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the delay values in a list, and just change the values based on which environment you are in.

If you were creating the workflow in Visual Studio, you could vary the delay value based on the host name of the site the workflow is running on.